# DatePicker widget filter a datetime field

Tags: yii2

Friends, how do I get my DatePicker component below (in Yii2 Framewok), filter a field of type `datetime`? Since in the component I can only specify the `date` format.

**_search.php** file:

```
<?php

    echo DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'start_date',
        'attribute2' => 'end_date',
        'language' => 'pt',
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
        'separator' => 'até',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => '',
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Report::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'created' => SORT_DESC, 
                ]
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 100,
                ],
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created' => $this->created,
            'updated' => $this->updated,
            'closed' => $this->closed,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'status_id' => $this->status_id,
            'location_id' => $this->location_id,
            'typeperson_id' => $this->typeperson_id,
            'field_cpfcnpj' => $this->field_cpfcnpj,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'created', $this->start_date, $this->end_date]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'closed', $this->start_closed, $this->end_closed]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: so you are looking to use the search file form with the datepicker to filter the results by **date & time** selection ?

Comment: I have the datetime type field and I want to filter all records in a given period (no matter the time). @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: add your `search()` method from the relative `SearchModel` that you are using

Comment: ok, updated @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to submit form using the date range which should filter the records using the given range.

Looking at you `search()` method it looks like you have declared 2 public properties/fields in the search model with the name `start_date` and `end_date` which you are using with the `DatePicker` and you are trying to compare the range with the column `created`.

You need to do the following in order to filter the records correctly

Make sure for the following

- The `start_date` and `end_date` are declared inside the `safe` rules for the `ReportSearch` model.
- You need to use the `\yii\db\Expression` to convert the date in the column to the desired format, and use the `php:date` to format the given date ranges i.e `start_date` and `end_date`.

Add the following before you return the `$dataProvider` in the `search()` method

```
if ($this->start_date !== null && $this->end_date !== null) {
    $query->andFilterWhere(
        [
            'BETWEEN',
            new Expression(
               'DATE_FORMAT(created,"%Y/%m/%d")'
            ),
            date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->start_date)),
            date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->end_date)),
        ]
    );
}
```

Note: if you have the `created` column saved as `timestamp` then you need to wrap the field name in the existing query with `FROM_UNIXTIME` like below, otherwise if the column is of `DATE` or `DATETIME` the above will work.

#### Column type is of TIMESTAMP

```
if ($this->start_date !== null && $this->end_date !== null) {
    $query->andFilterWhere(
        [
            'BETWEEN',
            new Expression(
                    'DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created),"%Y/%m/%d")'
                ),
            date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->start_date)),
            date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->end_date)),
        ]
    );
}
```

Your complete `search()` method will look like below

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Report::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'created' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created' => $this->created,
        'updated' => $this->updated,
        'closed' => $this->closed,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'status_id' => $this->status_id,
        'location_id' => $this->location_id,
        'typeperson_id' => $this->typeperson_id,
        'field_cpfcnpj' => $this->field_cpfcnpj,
    ]);

    if ($this->start_date !== null && $this->end_date !== null) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(
            [
                'BETWEEN',
                new Expression(
                    'DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y/%m/%d")'
                ),
                date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->start_date)),
                date("Y/m/d", strtotime($this->end_date)),
            ]
        );
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'closed', $this->start_closed, $this->end_closed]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```